# Foreign Key on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I started building my own project. I am having issues creating a foreign key on my second table. [image: code screenshot]. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: simply add bookid as Column to your entry table.

Comment: Simply adding `due_date` to `entry` will not make its foreign key declaration legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second CREATE TABLE statement should be:

```
CREATE TABLE entry (
    issuer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    issuer_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    fine INT,
    book_id INT,
    due_date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
        REFERENCES book_table (book_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (due_date)
        REFERENCES book_table (due_date)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

Comment: How is it possible for a foreign key to reference `book_table (due_date)` if `due_date` is not a unique key?

Comment: @LewBloch I don't know?? ask the original poster--it's not my application

Comment: I'm not the original poster and I'll answer my own question: it's not. I asked the question to stimulate thought.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a column or set of columns in one table that links to a unique key (typically the primary key) in another table. The columns must exist in both tables. They must match in type and the order within the key declarations. They must constitute a unique key in the foreign table.